# Rails ActionView::Helpers not resolving asset path correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I've got a small ruby module/class similar to this:

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass

    include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
    include ActionView::Context
    include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper 

    def test 
      puts "asset_url:  #{asset_url('poster.jpg')}"
      puts "asset_path: #{asset_path('poster.jpg')}"
    end
  end
end
```

and when I create a new instance of the class in a controller and then call the test method the result is:

```
asset_url:  /poster.jpg
asset_path: /poster.jpg
```

Which is not what I want/expect/hoped for!

But if I do this in a view:

```
= "asset_url:  #{asset_url('poster.jpg')}"
= "asset_path: #{asset_path('poster.jpg')}"
```

the result is:

```
asset_url:  http://localhost:3000/assets/poster.jpg 
asset_path: /assets/poster.jpg
```

Which is exactly what I want! So why does it give a different result in a module? And how can I get that correct asset path in my module? Thanks.

Comment: It may just be because there is no current location, no root url, in the module's scope. So when you call that module's methods it doesn't know what to build. You could hard code the path in, worst case scenario, but I'll be interested to see what others say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use methods from views and helpers in controllers you can use `view_context`.
For example:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def index
    logger.debug view_context.asset_url('poster.jpg')
    logger.debug view_context.asset_path('poster.jpg')
  end
end
```

`view_context` is just object (OK, this is object of Class :)), then you can pass it to any place you need (from controller).

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass

    def initialize(view_context)
      @view_context = view_context
    end

    def test 
      puts "asset_url:  #{@view_context.asset_url('poster.jpg')}"
      puts "asset_path: #{@view_context.asset_path('poster.jpg')}"
    end
  end
end
```

Or delegate methods to this object (Ruby feature):

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    delegate :asset_url, :asset_path, to: :@view_context

    def initialize(view_context)
      @view_context = view_context
    end

    def test 
      puts "asset_url:  #{asset_url('poster.jpg')}"
      puts "asset_path: #{asset_path('poster.jpg')}"
    end
  end
end
```